# What data should I use on predicting month values using linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, forecasting

Predicting next month values using linear regression.
I am using 6 month based historical values to predict future values.
I use vaccinated count on dependent variable and use months for independent variable and converted it to integer starts on 1.

Example.

Historical Data:

Month     dependent variable             independent variable
Jun              15                               1
Jul              14                               2
Aug              18                               3
Sep              19                               4
Oct              20                               5
Nov              22                               6

Is that correct?

Dependent Variable = Vaccinated Count
Independent Variable = Month converted to number start from 1

Expecting to give me some ideas if my data is correct

[See picture below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOVpL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Python simple linear regression:

```
Hardcover
Date    
2000-04-01  139
2000-04-02  128
2000-04-03  172
2000-04-04  139
2000-04-05  191


df['Time'] = np.arange(len(df.index))


          Hardcover     Time
  Date      
2000-04-01  139       0
2000-04-02  128       1
2000-04-03  172       2
2000-04-04  139       3
2000-04-05  191       4

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('Time', 'Hardcover', data=df, color='0.75')
ax = sns.regplot(x='Time', y='Hardcover', data=df, ci=None, scatter_kws=dict(color='0.25'))
ax.set_title('Time Plot of Hardcover Sales');
```

[image]